# linebreak in html php email

Tags: php, html-email

I am using below code to send a textarea content as email using php

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['emailbox'] ;
$message1 = $_REQUEST['output_textarea'];
$subject = 'script';
$message = "
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor='lightcyan'>
<p>heading</p>
$message1;
</table>
</body>
</html>
";
$headers  = "From: admin@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: acr@domain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

But the email ignoring all line breaks in the textarea. How can I keep the line break in text area ?

Comment: On ``$message1`` replace all ``\n`` characters with ``<br>``

Comment: just use BR tag for line break in html mail content

Comment: Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Beware of making things too easy for spam -- This script allows the user to send any message he wants to any address he wants; it's basically an open invitation to spammers to use your system to send as much junk as they like.

Comment: Also, you have a `<table>` tag in your HTML code which looks incorrect. You should probably replace it with a `<div>` unless you actually expect `$message1` to contain `<tr>` and `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, no semicolon needed here:

```
$message1;
```

As you use html for your email message, you have to use `<br/>`  tags to break lines.

Best way to replace `\n` with `<br/>` is use of [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) PHP function.

In your code replace:

```
$message1 = $_REQUEST['output_textarea'];
```

with:

```
$message1 = nl2br($_REQUEST['output_textarea']);
```

Comment: ` nl2br` means what why we need to use that

Comment: @sanojlawrence [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is a PHP function that inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it like this:

```
<?php
$message1 = $_REQUEST['output_textarea'];
$message1 = nl2br($message1);

?>
```